# How to create menu scrolling with mouse scrolling

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a part of my web to scroll with a page when it reaches the top while scrolling. So it gets stuck on the top and scrolls while I am scrolling. Something like this: 
http://www.sutanaryan.com/Tutorials/fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-CSS-and-jQuery/
But can it be done without jQuery, just with pure CSS3 and html5?

Comment: It can be done without JQuery, but it can't be done without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a persistent header, it's too long to explain so here's a link :
http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

Comment: This is the most simple way to do it. Not any way with purely html5 and css3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<ul class="scroll">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1 11</a></li>
</ul>
```

And **style.css**

```
ul#css3menu1 ul.scroll{
    max-height: 135px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```